# How to save set of types to a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in Postgres which returns setof of type `ctrlr_kpi_type`.

```
CREATE TYPE public.ctrlr_kpi_type AS
(
    door_id text,
    email text,
    android_id text,
    api_level integer,
    app_vers numeric,
    lattitude numeric,
    longitude numeric,
    oper_cd text,
    firmware_logic_ver text,
    safety_logic integer,
    hold_beam_type integer,
    sys_cycle_count integer,
    ctrlr_cycle_count integer,
    error_name text,
    powered_up_days integer,
    m1_err_cnt integer,
    m1_err_cycle_cnt integer,
    m2_err_cnt integer,
    m2_err_cycle_cnt integer,
    etl_insert_ts timestamp without time zone,
    reading_date timestamp without time zone,
    sap_equip_nbr text
);
```

Function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.controller_kpi(
    start_date date,
    end_date date)
    RETURNS SETOF ctrlr_kpi_type 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
     ..............
```

When I run the function using `select controller_kpi('2018-05-01', '2018-05-31')`, it returns a list of type `ctrlr_kpi_type`. However, it is shown as one column.

[image]

How do I break the type into columns based on the attributes so that I could save the result to a table and then export to csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change your call to the function adding FROM.

```
SELECT * FROM controller_kpi('2018-05-01', '2018-05-31')
```